# Is it possible to write an IQueryable extension for entity framework to use full text search?

Tags: full-text-search, entity-framework-6

I'm looking at my options for using full text search in entity framework 6, I'm almost at the point of going down the SQLQuery route but before I do just wondered would it be a good idea or even feasible to write an IQueryable Extension for EF to allow something like this

```
var books = myDbContext.Books.FullTextContains(x=>x.BookTitle, searchText).ToList()
```

or

```
var books = myDbContext.Books.FullTextFreeText(x=>x.BookTitle, searchText).ToList()
```

Im guessing this must be a solved problem?

Comment: I think you mean code first?

Comment: The model is defined using code first, yes

Comment: No chance. Even UDFs aren't supported: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2271

Comment: It looks like it should be possible to create an IQueryable extension method that uses an expression tree with the IQueryable provider to use the required TSQL for a full text search. If I get it working I'll post it here